# Query works in SQL Developer but not in a pass through query in Access

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ms-access-2007

I want to extract data from an Oracle 11g R2 database and import it in a table in Ms Access 2007.

I have a query that looks like :

```
SELECT * FROM aPublicSynonym
```

on the Oracle db using a READONLY user and it works fine in Oracle SQL Developer.But when I execute it as a pass-through query in ms Access I get:

```
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora] Ora-00942: table/view does not exist(#942)
```

I use the same ODBC data source with both sql developer and access and when I query in access :

```
select sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) from dual;
```

It works and returns the same user schema as in sql developer.
Can someone give me a hint about why i don't seem to have the privilege to access the public synonym when connecting with Access?
Thanks

Comment: Are you actually connected as the same user, or switching current schema after login? Are you sure you're connecting to the same instance?

Comment: You might have to name the schema explicitly (although I would not think so, if you're using a public synonym as the table name suggests). Also I would recommend putting the table name in all caps; it's possible Access is trying to pass a case-sensitive name to Oracle and the latter is choking on it. That is, use `APUBLICSYNONYM` and not `aPublicSynonym`.